# Нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, подлежащее

> Повествование в романе ведутся от имени трех рассказчиков: некого
>   странствующего офицера, штабс-капитана Масима Максимыча и, наконец,
>   самого Григория Александровича Печорина.

Где здесь нарушение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым в предложении заключается в том, что подлежащее **"повествование"** дано в единственном числе, сказуемое **"ведутся"** - во множественном числе. Чтобы исправить нарушение, нужно, чтобы подлежащее и сказуемое были в предложении в единственном числе (**сказуемое должно быть в том же ед.числе, что и подлежащее**) : ***Повествование*** в романе **ведётся** от имени трех рассказчиков: некого странствующего офицера, штабс-капитана Масима Максимыча и, наконец, самого Григория Александровича Печорина.

Comment: Должно быть: "НЕКОЕГО странствующего офицера" (http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/2378761/page:2/)

Answer (score 2):

Подлежащее и сказуемое согласуются, помимо прочего, по числу. Поэтому "повествование ведется" или "повествования ведутся", но здесь верно единственное число.

Замене "некоего" на "некого" допустимо, это явление современной разговорной речи. Хотя диссонирует, конечно, с темой о героях Лермонтова, в те времена это было бы, наверное, ошибкой.

Comment: Никогда не видел и не слышал, чтобы "некого" употреблялось вместо "некоего". На основании чего вы утверждаете, что это допустимо?